# Como fazer uma Classe ser propriedade de outra Classe? C#

Tags: c#, classes, herança

Estou fazendo um trabalho da facul que é pra controle de frota de veículos, criei uma classe Viagens e tentei colocar as classes Motorista e Veiculo nessa classe.

```
public Motorista {get; set;}
public Veiculo {get; set;}
```

Criei uma tela de cadastro para as viagens e no comando insert eu fiz assim:

```
Viagens viagens = new Viagens();
viagens.Motorista.CPF = txtCPF.Text;
viagens.Veiculo.Placa = txtPlaca.Text;
bll.InsertViagem(viagens);
```

Porém na hora de fazer o Insert eu recebo um erro "Referência de objeto não definida para a instância de um objeto"

O que eu preciso fazer pra não ter mais esse erro? Porque a minha classe Viagens precisa do CPF da classe Motorista e da Placa da classe Veiculo, pensei que dessa forma funcionária, mas não... Ficarei muito grato caso alguém ajude.

Comment: Entendeu a solução?

Answer (score 1):

Falta-lhe o nome das propriedades ou o tipo:

```
public Motorista {get; set;}
public Veiculo {get; set;}
```

Seria:

```
public Motorista Motorista {get; set;}
public Veiculo Veiculo {get; set;}
```

Você precisa tambem de instanciar a classe Motorista e Veiculo:

```
Motorista motorista = new Motorista();
motorista.CPF = txtCPF.Text;

Veiculo veiculo = new Veiculo();
veiculo.Placa = txtPlaca.Text;

Viagens viagens = new Viagens
{
    Motorista = motorista,
    Veiculo = veiculo 
};

bll.InsertViagem(viagens);
```

Answer (score 0):

Para acessar um membro de uma classe precisa antes de mais nada criar a sua instância, e a própria mensagem diz: ***Referência de objeto não definida para a instância de um objeto***, mas, como seria isso na prática:

***Classes***

```
public class Motorista
{

}
public class Veiculo
{

}
```

---

No próprio membro:

```
public class Viagens
{
    public Motorista Motorista { get; set; } = new Motorista(); // instância
    public Veiculo Veiculo { get; set; } = new Veiculo(); // instância
}
```

***ou***

No `construtor` da classe:

```
public class Viagens
{
    public Viagens()
    {              
        Motorista = new Motorista(); // instância
        Veiculo = new Veiculo(); // instância
    }
    public Motorista Motorista { get; set; }
    public Veiculo Veiculo { get; set; }
}
```

***ou até***

Depois da instância da principal, instanciar as seus membros complexos:

```
Viagens v = new Viagens();
v.Motorista = new Motorista();
v.Veiculo = new Veiculo();
```

Acredito que essas são as mais tradicionais e pode te ajudar a entender, que um dado complexo precisa ser instanciado para que possa acessar sua programação.